# Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4

Tags: apache-spark

i got a problem use spark : Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_4_piece0 of broadcast_4

this is my code :

```
public final class  SqlJoinJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("testRemoteHive")
                .master(x.x.x.x)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
       
        // use udf 
        spark.udf().register("sqlDecByDkUdf", new SqlDecByDkUdf(), DataTypes.StringType);

        String script = "select * from keyA a join keyB b on sqlDecByDkUdf(a.country, 'keyA') = sqlDecByDkUdf(b.country, 'keyB')";

        System.out.println("Executing script: " + script);
        spark.sql(script).show();
    }


// my udf 

public class SqlDecByDkUdf implements UDF2<String, String, String> {
    private static final String DOT_SEP = ",";
    private static final String COLONS_SEP= ":";

    @Override
    public String call(String uid, String keyName) throws Exception {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession().getOrElse(() ->
                SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("De-Identity Join Job")
                .master("spark://172.27.108.51:7077")
                .getOrCreate());

        String dkStr = spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().get("anonymization.encryption.key.list");
        HashMap<String, String> keyMap = parseDk(dkStr);
        String base64Dk = keyMap.get(keyName);
        return decrypt(uid, base64Dk);

    }
```

run the job parse exception, so how to fix it? thank you!!

i think the reason is multiple SparkSession ,so i try :

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession().getOrElse(() ->
                SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("De-Identity Join Job")
                .master("spark://172.27.108.51:7077")
                .getOrCreate());re
```

but it not works!